# Filters in Topology (Converge)

Tags: general-topology, filters

Let $X$ be an infinite set, $\mathscr{F}$ the filter on $X$ generated by the filter base consisting of all complements of finite sets. To which points does $\mathscr{F}$ converge if $X$ is given the cofinite topology?

I would suspect the answer to be every point in $X$. My reasoning, though may be wrong, is given below.

---

Let $\mathscr{C}$ denote the filter base, i.e. $\mathscr{C}:=\{A^c: A\subset X\text{ is finite}\}$ and $\mathscr{U}_x$ denote the set of all nhbds of $x$. The filter $\mathscr{F}$ converges to $x\in X$ iff each $U\in \mathscr{U}_x$ contains some $C\in\mathscr{C}$.

Notice,

$$C\subseteq U\iff U^c\subseteq C^c.$$

By definition of the topology, the set $U^c$ is finite, whereas by definition of the filter base, the set $C^c$ is infinite. Therefore, each $U\in \mathscr{U}_x$ contains some $C\in\mathscr{C}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that $\mathscr{C}$ is already a filter, so $\mathscr{F}=\mathscr{C}$. It’s true that $\mathscr{C}$ converges to every point of $X$, but there is an error in your argument: for any $C\in\mathscr{C}$ the set $C^c$ is by definition **finite**, not infinite. But since you haven’t actually picked any set $C\in\mathscr{C}$, this doesn’t say anything about a particular $U\in\mathscr{U}_x$. What you really should say here is that if $U\in\mathscr{U}_x$, then $X\setminus U$ is finite, so $U\in\mathscr{C}$. In fact, $\mathscr{U}_x=\{C\in\mathscr{C}:x\in C\}$ for each $x\in X$, and therefore $\mathscr{U}_x\subseteq\mathscr{C}$.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if $x \in X$, then any open neighbourhood of $x$ is of the form $F^\complement$, where $F$ is finite. By definition $F^\complement \in \mathcal{F}$ (It has finite complement so is in the filterbase), and so all (open) neighbourhoods of $x$ are in the filter and we have convergence $\mathcal{F}\to x$, for any $x$.